# How to get confetti effect in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to display a effect like confetti when player click the button. There is any way to get this by script or I need to use a preset pack with confetti?

Comment: Hey, there are several different ways to achieve what you're looking to do. In order to help you out, we would need a lot more information. Including things like what you've tried and what's your solutions haven't been able to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look to particle system ?

https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/particle-system